# Mounting a sparsebundle not working

Tags: time-machine, sparsebundle

I'm trying to mount a 3.5TB sparsebundle created by Time Machine. I've copied it into an external hard drive and double-clicked it.

After double-clicking it I see these messages on the Console app:

```
 -[DIStatFS logWithHeader:]: Input underlying FS: mounted on <private>, 131072 bytes 
block size, locally mounted from /dev/disk2s1

SparseBundleBackend::get_mounted_on_fs: <301> File system is exfat
```

But I can't see anything mounted on Finder. What might be the issue?